# Page refreshes by itself all the time

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook-graph-api

I just put a Facebook login button on my home page, and for some reason, when you are logged out of facebook, the page refreshes a few times when you visit it (only in Firefox) :)

Any idea why that happens?

The page is at http://www.comehike.com

Thanks!

Comment: Firefox 5.0.1 here, did not see any page refreshes and was logged out of Facebook.

Comment: @Devin thanks....it happens to me only when logged out of facebook.  Were you logged out?

Comment: Yep, if you could provide some steps to reproduce that would be great. Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 12, logged out, doesn't do it either

Comment: It's entirely possible you have some kind of extension or greasemonkey script that is doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run Firefox without the addons.

You'll have to use the process of elimination to find out which javascript is conflicting with Facebook's by turning each one off.

Once you've found it, try moving each `<script></script>` tag above or below other javascripts. Sometimes certain javascripts have to be loaded after other ones.